# Overlap multiple divs within parent div

Tags: html, css

This might be simple but I'm having problems getting this to work.

I'm using bootstrap and below is my css and div structure. How can I make `DIV 1` , `DIV 2` and `DIV 3` overlap? So basically I want to make `DIV 1` , `DIV 2` and `DIV 3`to be on the same level one behind the other.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/)

```
.sub{
    position: relative;
    background-color: lime;
}
.og{
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#itmHolder{
    position: absolute;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 og">
        <div class="itmHolder">
           <div class="sub">DIV 1</div>
           <div class="sub">DIV 2</div>
           <div class="sub">DIV 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="itmHolder">
           <button type="button" class="normalBtn">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected final output (`DIV 1` and `DIV 2` should be behind `DIV 3`):

[image]

Comment: @afzalex thanks but then the button (`.normalBtn`) moves to the same level of  `.sub`s?

Comment: `#itmHolder` vs. `.itmHolder`

Comment: Yes it will. Because when we made an element absolute then its size is not considered in its parent container. You will have to give size of its parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following CSS will give your expected output:

```
.itmHolder {
    position: relative;
}

.itmHolder :nth-child(2), .itmHolder :nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

#### Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/2/)

```css
.sub{
 position: relative;
    background-color: lime;
}
.itmHolder {
    position: relative;
}

.itmHolder :nth-child(2) , .itmHolder :nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
} 
.og{
 margin-top: 15px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
#itmHolder{
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 og">
        <div class="itmHolder">
           <div class="sub">DIV 1</div>
           <div class="sub">DIV 2</div>
           <div class="sub">DIV 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="itmHolder">
           <button type="button" class="normalBtn">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. looks good ketan. Let me try implementing your solution in my code. :)

Comment: Why are the elements stretched inside `.sub` divs? See example I've added 3 buttons insde `DIV 3` https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/3/

Comment: @Fergoso Give `.sub > button {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}` also to button. Check https://jsfiddle.net/t5au23ra/4/

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by setting `position` of elements to be `absolute` and specifying the size of its parent `element`.
Please have a look at below example.

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="og">
    <div class="itmHolder" id="cont" >
       <div class="sub" id="div1">DIV 1</div>
       <div class="sub" id="div2">DIV 2</div>
       <div class="sub" id="div3">DIV 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itmHolder">
       <button type="button" class="normalBtn" >Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to specify the size of parent element and want to make its size equal to the child's size then you can just leave any one child element to be `static` as shown below.

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="og">
    <div class="itmHolder" id="cont" >
       <div id="div1">DIV 1</div>
       <div class="sub" id="div2">DIV 2</div>
       <div class="sub" id="div3">DIV 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itmHolder">
       <button type="button" class="normalBtn" >Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In above example the size of `#cont` will be decided by `#div1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
        .dimension {
        height: 50px;
    }

    .overlap {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -50px;
        background-color: lime;
    }

    .og {
        margin-top: 15px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #itmHolder {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 og">
        <div class="itmHolder">
            <div class="dimension">DIV 1</div>
            <div class="dimension overlap">DIV 2</div>
            <div class="dimension overlap">DIV 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="itmHolder">
            <button type="button" class="normalBtn">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```